# Bumblebee dual monitor mirror Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, nvidia, bumblebee, optimus

I'm having troubles with configuring dual monitor with bumblebee.
Bumblebee and nvidia drivers were probably installed successfully - running `glxgears` and `optirun glxgears` give me totally different fps and `nvidia-settings` looks normally. 
Also after connecting external monitor to hdmi and running:

```
export DISPLAY=:8
optirun true
sleep 5
optirun glxgears
```

the glxgears shows up on the external monitor, so I suppose that everything is ok to that point.

But I don't know how to make xrandr work to have for example mirrored displays.
If I understand it correctly, using bumblebee it starts the second X server on `:8`, so there are running two X servers (primary, built-in monitor is on `:0` and second monitor using HDMI is on `:8)` so is this the problem? Is there any opportunity to have mirrored screens on different X servers?

I've tried a lot of tutorials, but almost each of them has different outputs using `xrandr` (probably becouse the HDMI wasn't connected to nvidia chip?). My outputs are:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+

$ export DISPLAY=:8
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 640mm x 360mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    24.00    23.97    60.00    50.04  
   1360x768      59.80  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00
```

The others had HDMI record in `:0` so they were able tu run `xrandr` with output targets .. but if i run for example

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --primary
$ xrandr --auto --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of XWAYLAND0
```

I get the expected error: `warning: output HDMI-0 not found; ignoring`

So the main question: How to configure X and bumblebee to have mirrored displays?

And of course my configs:

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Module"
    Load "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection
```

**/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf:**

```
$ cat /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=true
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia
Module=nvidia
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib64/nvidia-bumblebee:/usr/lib/nvidia-bumblebee:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib64/nvidia-bumblebee/xorg,/usr/lib64/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

**/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia**

```
cat /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "true"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"    
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"    
    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "true"
    #Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
 Option "IgnoreABI" "1" 
EndSection
```

**/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee-nvidia.conf**

```
$ cat /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee-nvidia.conf
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=true
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia
Module=nvidia
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib64/nvidia-bumblebee:/usr/lib/nvidia-bumblebee:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib64/nvidia-bumblebee/xorg,/usr/lib64/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```